# Is the shooter's face revealed in the Danish film Jagten?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunt

The Danish movie Jagten (2012), a.k.a The Hunt, ends with Mads Mikelsen escaping from a shooter. I remember that when I saw the movie, they had shown the shooter to be his son. But according to [the plot from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunt_%282012_film%29#Plot),

> On a hunting expedition to commemorate the event, an unseen person
>   apparently shoots at Lucas and misses him. Blinded by the setting sun,
>   Lucas is unable to identify his attacker, who is apparently reloading.
>   A moment later the unknown shooter, real or metaphor, is no longer ther.

Could anyone tell me if there are two ending versions of the film, or am I wrong here?

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of this discussion here http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/17592/23244 although the topic is also focused on the meaning of the ending. By the way, great movie and great performance by Mikkelsen